# Creating a collapsed range from a pixel position in FF/Webkit

Tags: javascript, range, position

Using JavaScript, I would like to create a collapsed range from a pixel position, in order to insert new nodes in the flow of the document, after the range identified by this position.

This can be done with the *TextRange* object in Internet Exporer (*moveToPoint(x, y)* method).

**How can I do this in FireFox & Webkit?**

I can get the container element from the position with *document.elementFromPoint(x, y)*. But when the position happens to be inside a text node, how do I get more information about the text offset required to build a range?

Comment: Wrapping each word of text with `<span>` is your best bet. I believe this thread has some other answers. (You won't be happy with them, though.) http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_thread/thread/eb5a58adbd8bf16d

Answer (score 21):

Here is my implementation of `caretRangeFromPoint` for old browsers:

```
if (!document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
    document.caretRangeFromPoint = function(x, y) {
        var log = "";

        function inRect(x, y, rect) {
            return x >= rect.left && x <= rect.right && y >= rect.top && y <= rect.bottom;
        }

        function inObject(x, y, object) {
            var rects = object.getClientRects();
            for (var i = rects.length; i--;)
                if (inRect(x, y, rects[i]))
                    return true;
            return false;
        }

        function getTextNodes(node, x, y) {
            if (!inObject(x, y, node))
                return [];

            var result = [];
            node = node.firstChild;
            while (node) {
                if (node.nodeType == 3)
                    result.push(node);
                if (node.nodeType == 1)
                    result = result.concat(getTextNodes(node, x, y));

                node = node.nextSibling;
            }

            return result;
        }

        var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        var nodes = getTextNodes(element, x, y);
        if (!nodes.length)
            return null;
        var node = nodes[0];

        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(node, 0);
        range.setEnd(node, 1);

        for (var i = nodes.length; i--;) {
            var node = nodes[i],
                text = node.nodeValue;


            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(node, 0);
            range.setEnd(node, text.length);

            if (!inObject(x, y, range))
                continue;

            for (var j = text.length; j--;) {
                if (text.charCodeAt(j) <= 32)
                    continue;

                range = document.createRange();
                range.setStart(node, j);
                range.setEnd(node, j + 1);

                if (inObject(x, y, range)) {
                    range.setEnd(node, j);
                    return range;
                }
            }
        }

        return range;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is the result of my investigation for getting a character position inside a text node from a pixel position:

- The standardized way: Get a range from a position with *document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y)*
  [See the spec at W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-documentview-caretrangefrompoint). This is exactly what I was looking for. The problem is that Chrome is the only web browser that implements this method as of this writing (July 2010)
- The MS IE way with the proprietary *textRange.moveToPoint(x, y)*.
- The Firefox way: If the pixel position (x, y) is retrieved from a mouse event, then Firefox will add two useful properties to the event object: *rangParent* and *rangeOffset*
- For Safari & Opera (and actually the only cross-browser method) is to re-constitute the containing boxes for text nodes, and then use the pixel position inside the containing box to infer the character position. To do this you must:

  1. Wrap all text nodes into <span> elements (dimension information is only available for elements, not for text nodes)
  2. Call *span.getClientRects()* to get the containing boxes for each textNode (wrapped into a <span>). If the text node spans over several lines you'll get several boxes.
  3. Find the box which contains your (x, y) pixel position, and infer the character position with a simple "rule of three" based on the total pixel width and text length.

Comment: The method suggested for Safari works in Safari 4, except when a zoom factor is applied to the page: in this case coordinates returned by getClientRects() are incorrect. Additionally Safari 3 does not even implement getClientRects(), so if you wan to support this browser the only method I can think of is to wrap all words inside all text nodes into SPANs!

Comment: Are you sharing this?  I work on FuncUnit (a testing solution) and this would be a useful addition.

Comment: The standardized way is actually `document.caretPositionFromPoint(x, y)`. Safari 5 and Chrome both support the WebKit-only `document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y)`.

Comment: Current versions of Opera and Safari implement `document.caretRangeFromPoint()` and the spec now has [`document.caretPositionFromPoint()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-document-caretpositionfrompoint)

Answer (score 5):

Under MSIE, you wrote:

```
var range = document.selection.createRange();
range.moveToPoint(x, y);
```

For other browsers, the idea is to determine the HTML element at x/y position and to create a one character selection on it. Based on `range.getBoundingClientRect()`, you can determine if the one character selection if before or after the x/y position. We then can select the next character until the selection position raich the x/y position. I wrote the following implementation for Firefox, Safari and Chrome:

```
var nodeInfo = getSelectionNodeInfo(x, y);
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(nodeInfo.node, nodeInfo.offsetInsideNode);
range.setEnd(nodeInfo.node, nodeInfo.offsetInsideNode);

/**
Emulates MSIE function range.moveToPoint(x,y) b
returning the selection node info corresponding
to the given x/y location.

@param x the point X coordinate
@param y the point Y coordinate
@return the node and offset in characters as 
{node,offsetInsideNode} (e.g. can be passed to range.setStart) 
*/
function getSelectionNodeInfo(x, y) {
    var startRange = document.createRange();
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(startRange);

    // Implementation note: range.setStart offset is
    // counted in number of child elements if any or
    // in characters if there is no childs. Since we
    // want to compute in number of chars, we need to
    // get the node which has no child.
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    var startNode = (elem.childNodes.length>0?elem.childNodes[0]:elem);
    var startCharIndexCharacter = -1;
    do {
        startCharIndexCharacter++;
        startRange.setStart(startNode, startCharIndexCharacter);
        startRange.setEnd(startNode, startCharIndexCharacter+1);
        var rangeRect = startRange.getBoundingClientRect();
    } while (rangeRect.left<x && startCharIndexCharacter<startNode.length-1);

    return {node:startNode, offsetInsideNode:startCharIndexCharacter};
}
```

These two piece of code have been tested under :

- MSIE 7, MSIE 9
- Firefox 5, Firefox 10
- Chrome 9
- Safari 5

The following situations were not tested:

- zooming factor issues
- HTML elements with more than one text line

Comment: Don't know why this answer has been largely ignored, it's the most useful answer for dozens of questions here. I'll post code that accounts for multiple lines soon, I hope.

Answer (score 3):

The situation has changed since this question and most of the answers were posted: all major browsers now have at least one of the methods that make this relatively simple:

- The standards-based approach from the CSSOM View spec: [`document.caretPositionFromPoint()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-document-interface)
- WebKit's proprietary version of the same: `document.caretRangeFromPoint()`
- IE's proprietary `TextRange` object, which has a [`moveToPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method that takes pixel coordinates. However, it seems that `moveToPoint()` can be buggy (see [here](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11074) and [here](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/dstorey/internet_explorer_11_review_part_1_40/#comment-1153775544), for example); I've simply been lucky that has worked in all the documents I've used it in.

Note that in IE up to and including version 11, the object produced is a `TextRange` rather than a DOM `Range`. In versions of IE that support `Range`, there is no easy way to convert between the two, although if you're willing to mess with the selection you can do something like the following, assuming you have a TextRange stored in a variable called `textRange`:

```
textRange.select();
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

Here's some example code. It works in IE 5+, Edge, Safari and Chrome from around 2010 onwards, Firefox >= 20 and Opera >= 15.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/rhgyw2dg/

Code:

```
function createCollapsedRangeFromPoint(x, y) {
    var doc = document;
    var position, range = null;
    if (typeof doc.caretPositionFromPoint != "undefined") {
        position = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(x, y);
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.setStart(position.offsetNode, position.offset);
        range.collapse(true);
    } else if (typeof doc.caretRangeFromPoint != "undefined") {
        range = doc.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y);
    } else if (typeof doc.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToPoint(x, y);
    }
    return range;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension of Julien's answer above. This copes with multiple lines. Needs a little tweaking, but seems to work. It finds the number of lines by getting the height of a start to end selection, and the height of a single-letter selection, dividing the two, and rounding. There are probably situations where that won't work, but for most purposes...

```
function getLineCount(node, range) {
    if ((node) && (range)) {
        range.setStart(node, 0);
        range.setEnd(node, 1);
        var r = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        var h1 = r.bottom - r.top;
        range.setEnd(node, node.length);
        r = range.getBoundingClientRect();
        return Math.round((r.bottom - r.top) / h1);
    }
};
```

Here's a tweaked version of the above code, using the line-count routine above. It also copes a little better with selections within the node, but off to the right of the actual text. None of this is optimized, but we're in user-time here, so milliseconds likely aren't too important.

```
function getSelectionNodeInfo(x, y) {
    var startRange = document.createRange();
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(startRange);

    // Implementation note: range.setStart offset is
    // counted in number of child elements if any or
    // in characters if there is no childs. Since we
    // want to compute in number of chars, we need to
    // get the node which has no child.
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    console.log("ElementFromPoint: " + $(elem).attr('class'));
    var startNode = (elem.childNodes.length>0?elem.childNodes[0]:elem);

    var lines = getLineCount(startNode, startRange);
    console.log("Lines: " + lines);

    var startCharIndexCharacter = 0;
    startRange.setStart(startNode, 0);
    startRange.setEnd(startNode, 1);
    var letterCount = startNode.length;
    var rangeRect = startRange.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rangeWidth = 0

    if (lines>1) {
        while ((rangeRect.bottom < y) && (startCharIndexCharacter < (letterCount-1))) {
            startCharIndexCharacter++;
            startRange.setStart(startNode, startCharIndexCharacter);
            startRange.setEnd(startNode, startCharIndexCharacter + 1);
            rangeRect = startRange.getBoundingClientRect();
            rangeWidth = rangeRect.right - rangeRect.left
        }
    }
    while (rangeRect.left < (x-(rangeWidth/2)) && (startCharIndexCharacter < (letterCount))) {
        startCharIndexCharacter++;
        startRange.setStart(startNode, startCharIndexCharacter);
        startRange.setEnd(startNode, startCharIndexCharacter + ((startCharIndexCharacter<letterCount) ? 1 : 0));
        rangeRect = startRange.getBoundingClientRect();
        rangeWidth = rangeRect.right - rangeRect.left
    }

    return {node:startNode, offsetInsideNode:startCharIndexCharacter};
}
```

Comment: I imagine this works for most situations and I've had a go at doing a similar thing myself a few years ago (http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/ABjQP/8/), but it's not necessary now.