# In Webkit, how do I add another word to the range?

Tags: javascript, webkit, range, textrange

Suppose I've made my range so that it covers a word, using `range.expand('word')`.  Typically to add the next word, I would write `range.moveEnd('word', 1)`.  But this seems not to work in Webkit.  Perhaps it should be implemented differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about `TextRange`s, which are only fully implemented in IE. Other browsers use the [DOM Level 2 Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) objects instead, which while being vastly superior to TextRanges in most ways have no equivalent of text-based methods such as `expand()`. However, recent WebKit browsers do implement a version of `expand()` and both Webkit and Firefox 4 have the [`modify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection/modify) method of the `Selection` object which provides similar functionality.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bzU22/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function expandSelection() {
        if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().modify) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.moveEnd("word", 1);
            range.select();
        }
        document.getElementById("test").focus();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" unselectable onclick="expandSelection();" value="Expand">
<p contenteditable="true" id="test">Hello, this is some test text.
    Select a word and then press the 'Expand' button.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I was using var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(x,y) before.  Is there an equivalent so that I can use sel.modify?

Comment: Browsers have varying APIs for this. This question has more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189812/creating-a-collapsed-range-from-a-pixel-position-in-ff-webkit