# Chrome caret invisible in inactive window - bad for drag&drop

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, caret

When dragging something over a contenteditable area in Chrome, to be able to catch the 'drop' event, one needs to call `e.preventDefault();` on every 'dragover' event.

This hides the caret, which tells you where you are going to drop. This can be circumvented by manually updating the caret position via [document.caretRangeFromPoint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654262/drop-image-into-contenteditable-in-chrome-to-the-cursor).

This works perfectly unless the window is inactive - then the caret is invisible.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zupa/mezAm/

Is there a way to make it visible *without* using a helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you don't *HAVE TO* call `e.preventDefault()` in the `dragover` event, which leaves you with the cursor shown even if the window is inactive. (So the default browser behaviour is to show the drop caret.) All the tutorials state that you MUST call it to be able to catch the `drop` event. I believe you only need to `return false`.

I have only tested that with **Firefox** 13.0.1 and **Chrome** 19.0.1084.56 (Other browsers have not yet implemented the `drop` event as per now.)