# JavaScript detect text offset in node at position

Tags: javascript, position, selection, offset

I would like to detect the element and text offset under the specified x and y co-ordinates.

Let's say we have such DOM:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nam quis nisl lectus. Donec euismod dignissim turpis, nec 
viverra nulla iaculis nec. _Fusce_ mattis orci eget nibh 
rhoncus auctor at in enim.
</p>
```

When the user clicks the mouse just before the word `_Fusce_` having the x and y co-ordinates I would like to obtain the offset of the word `_Fusce_` in the text node as an index. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebKit has `document.caretRangeFromPoint()` for this. The CSSOM View spec has [`document.caretPositionFromPoint()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-document-interface), but only [Firefox 20 and later currently implements it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.caretPositionFromPoint).

In Firefox, if the position you're interested in has come from a mouse event then you can get this information direct from the event, which has properties `rangeParent` and `rangeOffset`.

Here's a similar question with some example code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659990/96100