# Text selection in div(contenteditable) when double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, textselection

I have div with some text and contenteditable="true". When I single click on this div - works some my scripts, it is not very important. And when I double click on this div - need to edit text in div. Edit text need to be only after double click, not after single. And very imortant, when I double click on div - caret need stay under mouse cursor. No need selection text. I found some script for single/double. But have problem. When I double click on div - text are selection. Selection no need. Need editor caret where I clicked. I do not understand how.
http://jsfiddle.net/X6auM/

Comment: Single-click-to edit is the expected result for `contenteditable` element. If you want to use double-click, set the `contenteditable` *only* when the element is double-clicked. Once editable, focus to the element, then set the caret based on the mouse position from the double-click event. Finally, when focus is lost, disable the `contenteditable`.

Comment: I do not understand how to place the cursor exactly at the place where there was a click. This with .focus(). But caret go to start of line. http://jsfiddle.net/jupUh/

Comment: How can I find the position of caret if it has not been in div?

Comment: I found script which get caret position. Script works but not in this situation. http://jsfiddle.net/9Z3bp/1/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Every current major browser provides an API to create a range from a mouse event, although there are four different code branches needed.

Here is some background:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659990/96100
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705894/96100
- [Creating a collapsed range from a pixel position in FF/Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3189812/96100)

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/krtTD/10/

And here's some code:

```
function getMouseEventCaretRange(evt) {
    var range, x = evt.clientX, y = evt.clientY;

    // Try the simple IE way first
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToPoint(x, y);
    }

    else if (typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        // Try Mozilla's rangeOffset and rangeParent properties,
        // which are exactly what we want
        if (typeof evt.rangeParent != "undefined") {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(evt.rangeParent, evt.rangeOffset);
            range.collapse(true);
        }

        // Try the standards-based way next
        else if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
            var pos = document.caretPositionFromPoint(x, y);
            range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(pos.offsetNode, pos.offset);
            range.collapse(true);
        }

        // Next, the WebKit way
        else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
            range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y);
        }
    }

    return range;
}

function selectRange(range) {
    if (range) {
        if (typeof range.select != "undefined") {
            range.select();
        } else if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("editor").ondblclick = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    this.contentEditable = true;
    this.focus();
    var caretRange = getMouseEventCaretRange(evt);

    // Set a timer to allow the selection to happen and the dust settle first
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        selectRange(caretRange);
    }, 10);
    return false;
};
```

Comment: It's amazing! Yesterday I made a few other methods. But does not work very well. Your version works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work when element is inside the `#shadow-root` thingy.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').dblclick(function(event) {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.attr('contenteditable', "true");
  $this.blur();
  $this.focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krtTD/90/

Comment: A suggestion, your answer would be complete if you explained what you were doing as well.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../tailwind.css" /> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="editor" style="user-select:none;" contenteditable="false">Some editableasa text. Double click to eadsit</div>
    <script>
        function getMouseEventCaretRange(evt) {
            var range, x = evt.clientX, y = evt.clientY;

            // Try the simple IE way first
            if (document.body.createTextRange) {
                range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToPoint(x, y);
            }

            else if (typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
                // Try Mozilla's rangeOffset and rangeParent properties, which are exactly what we want

                if (typeof evt.rangeParent != "undefined") {
                    range = document.createRange();
                    range.setStart(evt.rangeParent, evt.rangeOffset);
                    range.collapse(true);
                }

                // Try the standards-based way next
                else if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
                    var pos = document.caretPositionFromPoint(x, y);
                    range = document.createRange();
                    range.setStart(pos.offsetNode, pos.offset);
                    range.collapse(true);
                }

                // Next, the WebKit way
                else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
                    range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y);
                }
            }

            return range;
        }

        function selectRange(range) {
            if (range) {
                if (typeof range.select != "undefined") {
                    range.select();
                } else if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
                    var sel = window.getSelection();
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
            }
        }


        document.getElementById("editor").ondblclick = function (evt) {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            this.contentEditable = true;

            this.focus();
            var caretRange = getMouseEventCaretRange(evt);
            selectRange(caretRange);
            this.style = ""
        };

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

An improvement of accepted answer that does not create the temp flash it uses css user-select property to it's advantage