# How to convert the `selectionRect` (point x and y coordinates ) of the electron`context-menu` params to a DOM Range?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, electron

How to convert the `selectionRect` of the `context-menu` params to a Range?

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-context-menu

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

I've found this explanation: [How to create a Range Object from a point (X and Y Coordinates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643515/how-to-create-a-range-object-from-a-point-x-and-y-coordinates)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretPositionFromPoint

but with:

```
let range: Range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(selectionRect.x, selectionRect.y)
console.log("App_S-range: ", range)
```

I get :

```
selectionRect{
    "x": 675,
    "y": 205,
    "width": 69,
    "height": 92
}


App_S-range:  
Range 
collapsed: true
commonAncestorContainer: div.ant-space.css-dev-only-do-not-override-diro6f.ant-space-
horizontal.ant-space-align-center
endContainer: div.ant-space.css-dev-only-do-not-override-diro6f.ant-space-
horizontal.ant-space-align-center
endOffset: 0
startContainer: div.ant-space.css-dev-only-do-not-override-diro6f.ant-space-
horizontal.ant-space-align-center
startOffset: 0
```

And it shouldn't be `collapsed`