# contenteditable on doubleclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I've got a `p` tag with some text, and I'm trying to make it `contenteditable` but only on doubleclick. How can I prevent browser from placing the cursor on the p when I click on it and only do it when I doubleclick? JQuery:

```
    p.dblclick(function(e){
        p.css("cursor", "text");
    })
    .focusout(function(){
        p.css("cursor", "default");
    })
    .click(function(e){
        console.log('focus p');
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("body").focus(); // not stopping Chrome from placing cursor
    });
```

I could make `contenteditable` false by default and then make it true on `dbleclick` and then do `p.focus()` but it means I can't place cursor where I clicked. On the other hand, I could make it contenteditable after first click and then wait like 1.5s for a dobuleclick and if it didn't happen cancel it, but if it happened, then the content would be editable and the second click would trigger the placement of the cursor in the right place. However, it's not that smooth and makes the content editable for these 1 and a half seconds.

## Any ideas?

answer:
In case somebody is interested, I went on to implement the timer method, because I don't think there's any other way... here's the code

```
var DELAY = 700, clicks = 0, timer = null;
p.focusout(function(){
    p.css("cursor", "default");
    p.prop("contenteditable", false);
})
.click(function(e){
    clicks++;
    p.prop("contenteditable", true);
    if(clicks == 1){
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            p.prop("contenteditable", false);
            //alert("Single Click");  //perform single-click action
            clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
        }, DELAY);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);    //prevent single-click action
       // alert("Double Click");  //perform double-click action
        clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
    }

});
```

Comment: Please, refer to the documentation.
http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ And read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12924488/96100

Answer (score 7):

try this    here a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UVH3/)

```
 <p ondblclick="this.contentEditable=true;this.className='inEdit';" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;this.className='';" contenteditable="false" class="">This paragraph uses some simple script to be editable. Double-click the text to begin editing.</p>
```

Comment: it's illustrating my point -- on doubleclick it becomes editable, and requires one more click to start editing. But I want it to be able to start editing straight after doubleclick AND place the cursor where I click

Comment: @zavr add `this.focus();` in dblclick

Comment: This worked well, I adjusted the `ondblclick` to `onclick` so the first click makes the content editable and the second click selects, don't need to focus.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution which works for me:

```
<script>
function listenForDoubleClick(element) {
  element.contentEditable = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.activeElement !== element) {
      element.contentEditable = false;
    }
  }, 300);
}
</script>

<p onclick="listenForDoubleClick(this);" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;">Double-click the text to begin editing.</p>
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtL3xzfb/

It uses a timeout event to check if the text has been selected within a certain period of time (300ms), if the text is not selected (by a second click) it will set content editable to false again: The content editable parameter is set to true after the first click so text will be selected when you click for a second time.

Comment: Perfect! +1.  I'll only add a background color to hint that something is changed in the DOM. When contentEditable goes back to false, the background color will be set back to original.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the text unselectable as in [How to disable text selection using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery) :

```
var p = $('p');

p.attr('unselectable', 'on')
    .css('user-select', 'none')
    .on('selectstart', false);

p.dblclick(function (e) {
    p.css("cursor", "text")
        .attr('contenteditable', true)
        .attr('unselectable', 'off')
        .css('user-select', 'inherit')
        .off('selectstart', false)
        .focus();

});

p.focusout(function () {
    p.css("cursor", "default")
        .attr('unselectable', 'on')
        .attr('contenteditable', false)
        .css('user-select', 'none')
        .on('selectstart', false);
});
```

Comment: thanks. although the text is not selectable, the text cursor is still placed in Chrome (and I can use arrows to move it around).

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "the text cursor is still placed", and I don't see it in my Chrome test environment.

Comment: i tried setting focus manually but it's not the solution because I don't get cursor placed where I clicked

Answer (score 0):

If using React you may use the component

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import { useState } from 'react'

const inputValue = (e: any): string => e.target.value

function isEnterOrEscapeKeyEvent(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    return event.key === 'Enter' || event.key === 'Escape'
}

const EditOnDblClick = () => {
    const [isEditing, setisEditing] = useState(false)
    const [text, settext] = useState('yoga chitta')

    const onEditEnd = () => {
        setisEditing(false)
    }

    return isEditing ? (
        <input
            value={text}
            className="bg-transparent border-2 border-black border-solid"
            onKeyDown={(event) => {
                if (isEnterOrEscapeKeyEvent(event)) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                    onEditEnd()
                }
            }}
            onChange={_.flow(inputValue, settext)}
            onBlur={onEditEnd}
            autoFocus
        />
    ) : (
        <div className="select-none" onDoubleClick={() => setisEditing(true)}>
            {text}
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditOnDblClick
```

Note: Classes are from tailwindcss