# i want html table to be editable on double click only with jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i want to have my `table` `editable` on `double` `click` how would i do that.

[image]

**below is what i have tried**

```js
$(function(){
  $('.zui-table').find('td').dblclick(function(){
     
  });
});
```

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="zui-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Born</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable>DeMarcus Cousins</td>
      <td contenteditable>C</td>
      <td contenteditable>6'11"</td>
      <td contenteditable>08-13-1990</td>
      <td contenteditable>$4,917,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Mr.x The single click is the problem, i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `contenteditable` as `attr` on `click`. With this solution you don't need to use `dblclick`, because in first `click` you add `attr` then on second `click` you can `edit` your content.

```js
$('.zui-table').find('td').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $('.zui-table td').not($(this)).prop('contenteditable', false);
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
  });
  $(this).blur(function() {
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
  });
});
```

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="zui-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Height</th>
      <th>Born</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DeMarcus Cousins</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>6'11"</td>
      <td>08-13-1990</td>
      <td>$4,917,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Edit: on this **[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172465/contenteditable-on-doubleclick)** you can find `javascript` solution, but here is `jquery` simple solution. I deleted my answer but after that i thought maybe this need beside that topic, and for future.*

Comment: Your solution needs 3 clicks

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks, I didn't realize that time. Now it works.

Comment: Ya this is better even if for doubleclick both click have to be done in a specific laps of time. Here, you can click once, wait ten minutes, then reclick it would make the TD editable BUT it isn't a doubleclick. That's said, i guess it is acceptable behaviour for OP :) You could of course handle it using a timeout but i'm not sure it worth it

Comment: @A.Wolff Yeah, this line `$('.zui-table td').not($(this)).prop('contenteditable', false);` maybe make it better. if you click once, then click on other `td` it `false` `contenteditable`, but still a little buggy, if you don't click on other `td` or `blur` it `contenteditable` on next click.

Comment: Anyway i guess your answer is an acceptable one but i'm not OP...