# Focus a contenteditable div after double clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, focus, contenteditable

I have a div that is initially has contenteditable=false.

```
<div contenteditable="false" tabindex='1' style="width:100px;height:100px" id="my_div" >def text</div>
```

I want to make it contenteditable=true `and` focus it after double click.

```
function make_focus()
{
$("#my_div").prop('contenteditable','true'); 
$("#my_div").focus();   
}

$(function() {

    $("#my_div").dblclick(function(e)
    {
    make_focus();
    })

});
```

If i call make_focus() `directly`, without dblclick event like this

```
<input type=button value='make focus' onclick="make_focus()">
```

then i get #my_div focused `the way i need`. However, `when i check how it works with dblclick` then i get a different result. The first thing is that after double click the text gets selected and `i don't need it`. The second thing is that `in IE the div doesn't get focused after double click`. Again, i want that double click to work like the function that is called directly.
Here is the link to jsfiddle that shows how it should work
http://jsfiddle.net/cH3Xs/14/ . And another link that shows how it should not work(please, check in IE) http://jsfiddle.net/Vr8yB/5/

**P.S**. following solution seems to work:[Text selection in div(contenteditable) when double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920225/text-selection-in-divcontenteditable-when-double-click?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:800px;height:100px" ondblclick="this.contentEditable=true;" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;this.className='';" contenteditable="false">Double click to see</div>
```