# HTML: Text in block-element; get exact position of click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery-click-event

I need to now *where* in a html block-element that contains only text a click happened:

```
<div>This is some awesome text</div>
```

I would like to get the position of the letter that was clicked.
Limitation: it is not possible to add additional childs to the div.

Any options?

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @j08691 I have not yet tried anything - I was wondering how to do this. And Google did not provide any results. In a mouseclick-handler I only get the position of the mouse and I know, which element emitted the event (in my case so far the div) - but still the exact position in relation to the text is still not known.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12924488/96100

Comment: @TimDown thanks for this solution - range is the way to go for me.
And thanks for showing me _contenteditable_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution I adopted thanks to @TimDown is taken from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.caretPositionFromPoint).

```
function insertBreakAtPoint(e) {

var range;
var textNode;
var offset;

if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {    // standard
    range = document.caretPositionFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    textNode = range.offsetNode;
    offset = range.offset;

} else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {    // WebKit
    range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    textNode = range.startContainer;
    offset = range.startOffset;
}

// do whatever you want here!
}
```

There is one limitation (at least I have a small problem in Chromium) that the range.textNode must not necessarily identical to the one that was clicked. The contained text might be shorter than expected. Reason for that remained unknown.
I just did the access via *range.textNode.parentElement.firstChild* as in my case the div only has one child.

Comment: There doesn't seem a way to get the position of a textNode at all with no mouse click

Comment: thanks a lot, worked nicely
I've found the following reference helpful as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the offsets of the current element to get the position of the click relative to the element ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yzd5k/)):

```
$(function () {
    $("#awesome").click(function (event) {
      var div = $(this);  
      var posX = event.pageX - div.offset().left;
      var posY = event.pageY - div.offset().top;

      alert("X: " + posX + " Y: " + posY);
    });
});
```

You will have to do other calculations to figure out which letter was clicked.

Comment: That's actually not solving the problem - it might be a useful step, but the calculation of the "rendered" (CSS) string length is problematic.

Comment: Did some work on how to follow this approach - first option is to use a monospace font (quite a limitation) or calculate the real font size using Canvas2D (probably not very efficient).