# jQuery UI droppable insert with caret to contenteditable

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, jquery-ui-draggable, caret, jquery-ui-droppable

My question is very specific, but im not shure how to do this best:

I have a jQuery draggable and droppable, so a draggable can drop in specific droppables. All my droppables are DIVs with contenteditable="true" and now i want to insert some code (or for easy: the draggable) at the hovering cursor position.

So first i need to show up a caret beyond the cursor, when a element is dragged. (They are alphatransparent so you can see-through the caret). But how do i get the caret-position thats equal to the actual mousecursor?

Comment: I think this question covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654262/drop-image-into-contenteditable-in-chrome-to-the-cursor/10659990#10659990

Comment: Thank you! Took me to the right place.