# Get Firefox contenteditable drag-and-drop cursor position on dragover/drop event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, range, caret

I'm trying to put together an image uploader. I want to upload images into a contenteditable area with drag-and-drop.

As I drag the file, I see the cursor moving - unless e.preventDefault() was called.

In Chrome, there is a function [`document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654262/drop-image-into-contenteditable-in-chrome-to-the-cursor) to convert coordinates to cursor position (range).
As far as I'm reading, there is no such in Firefox. (please prove mo wrong)

Is that moving cursor which I can see to be catched somehow? Maybe in the dragover/drop event? As for my experiments, it is not accessible as a range in the dragover event. I wish I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bumped into the answer in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189812/creating-a-collapsed-range-from-a-pixel-position-in-ff-webkit) (after having my own caretPositionFromPoint implemented, damn it :D)

In Firefox, you can simply access it in event.rangeParent and event.rangeOffset respectively.

Hope this saves someone's butt.

Answer (score 1):

The standards-based method that all browsers will hopefully eventually support is [`document.caretPositionFromPoint()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-document-interface) and <strike>Firefox doesn't support it yet. There is an open bug on it though:</strike>

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654352

**Update**

Firefox has supported this since version 20.

Comment: Yeah I've bumped into that, but this basically means we can only use this method in a few years.. You are becoming my mentor^^