# Set a selection range from A to B in absolute position

Tags: javascript

How can I select programmatically from A(x1,y1) to B(x2,y2) ?

x1, y1, x2, y2 are pixel coordinates. I searched a lot and in all functions I found, we had to specify a specific tag and then it selects its content.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on what you're trying to do? What are A and B, for instance?

Comment: I'm sure you can make this question a little better and explain with more details what you're trying to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There is not really A and B. When you drag with your mouse and select a text it's from (30,43) to (343,234) for exemple. And I want to have the selection you would have with these numbers

Comment: are you talking about highlighting text in an input box? this is done by character, not by pixel.

Comment: @jbabey I mean selecting like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/KcX6A/339/

Comment: So A and B are pixel coordinates?

Comment: @user1365010 if you read the documentation for the methods that the fiddle is using to highlight text, i'm sure you can figure out how to tweak it to accept `start` and `end` values. (Hint: [start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.setStart) and [end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.setEnd))

Comment: I'd suggest adding a bit of detail to the question for searchability etc.

Comment: @jbabey the selection start and end aren't really specified as coordinates. They just say *select the content of this tag*.

Comment: @user1365010 they will never be specified by pixel coordinates, as i said earlier. highlighted is by text node or by characters in text nodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight text range using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240139/highlight-text-range-using-javascript)

Comment: @jbabey: No, it's not a duplicate. It's about creating a text selection from pixel coordinates, not character offsets or highlighting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this in current versions of all browsers. These browsers have at least one of the following:

- The standards-based approach, implemented by Firefox >= 20, from the CSSOM View spec: [`document.caretPositionFromPoint()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-document-interface)
- WebKit's proprietary version of the same: `document.caretRangeFromPoint()`.
- IE's proprietary `TextRange` object, which has a [`moveToPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method that takes pixel coordinates. However, it seems that `moveToPoint()`, which is used in all version of IE, can be buggy (see [here](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11074) and [here](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/dstorey/internet_explorer_11_review_part_1_40/#comment-1153775544), for example); I've simply been lucky that has worked in all the documents I've used it in.

<strike>However, Mozilla does not yet implement any of these and neither does Opera, so this can't be done in those browsers yet.</strike>

**[Firefox 20 and later supports `document.caretPositionFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.caretPositionFromPoint). Opera 15 supports `document.caretRangeFromPoint()`**

Here's some example code. It works in IE 5+, WebKit from around 2010 onwards, Firefox >= 20 and Opera >= 15.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/ABjQP/

Code:

```
function createSelectionFromPoint(startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    var doc = document;
    var start, end, range = null;
    if (typeof doc.caretPositionFromPoint != "undefined") {
        start = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(startX, startY);
        end = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(endX, endY);
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.setStart(start.offsetNode, start.offset);
        range.setEnd(end.offsetNode, end.offset);
    } else if (typeof doc.caretRangeFromPoint != "undefined") {
        start = doc.caretRangeFromPoint(startX, startY);
        end = doc.caretRangeFromPoint(endX, endY);
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.setStart(start.startContainer, start.startOffset);
        range.setEnd(end.startContainer, end.startOffset);
    }
    if (range !== null && typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof doc.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToPoint(startX, startY);
        var endRange = range.duplicate();
        endRange.moveToPoint(endX, endY);
        range.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", endRange);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1365010: You HTML can't see the `createSelectionFromPoint()` function because it's defined inside a `load` handler. Here's an update: http://jsfiddle.net/jz7Jx/2/

Comment: No the bug is because I was in firefox :( There is really no way to do this for firefox ?

Comment: @user1365010: Well, it wasn't working in Chrome either because of the problem I mentioned :) I can't think of an easy way to do this in Firefox off the top of my head.

Comment: I will accept your answer, but if you find a way working with the current version of firefox (and opera?) I'll give you a bounty of 100 :D

Comment: The only way of doing it in Firefox that occurred to me was a slightly complicated way of doing it using trial and error and the `getBoundingClientRect()` method of ranges. Here's an answer that uses this (I haven't tested it though, and it doesn't look quite right): http://stackoverflow.com/a/3710561

Comment: @user1365010: Actually, this answer is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9603270/96100. I may incorporate it into mine later.

Comment: @vasanth: That answer uses the same technique as my answer, namnely `doc.caretRangeFromPoint()`, but without the fallbacks for other browsers.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with page scroll? So that dy distance between startY and endY could be more than screen height

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox or Opera there is a little workaround. This set the caret at the first position of an element:

```
console.log("moz or opera doesn't support caret by position so we have a workaround");
var range = doc.createRange();
var element = doc.elementFromPoint(startX, startY);
range.setStart(element, 0);
```